# Why is the span of a vector a line through the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

Why is the span of a vector a line **through the origin**?

I understand the "formal" definition of a span and its motivation. It is the set of all linear combinations of the vectors given and the idea is to span lines or planes with certain vectors.

Visually we represent vectors as arrows with a lenght and a direction - and very importantly the arrow can be displaced and we still have the same vector. This is helpful for adding and scaling vectors visually.

However, now my question is suppose we have the vector (1,1). We can represent it as an arrow for example at the origin or also at another point (0,1). But if we "span" these two different arrows (still the same vector) we get two different lines - one passing through the origin and the other not. But obviously we have to differentiate these lines as they are now longer vectors anymore?

I read somewhere that the spane of a vector always is a line through the origin - so all other lines are therefore not spans? Do we always have to take the represting arrow fixed at the orgigin of a given vector? And if yes - where is it mentioned in the formal definition?

> In short: Why isn't the span of a vector all possible lines with the same direction of the vector and only the line through the origin?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a vector starting at any point in space (what physicists call a "free vector") is sometimes useful, but not part of the formalization of the mathematical concept of a vector space. There the span of $v = (1,1)$ is the set of real multiples of $v$.

Comment: So in math the vector "starts" at zero?

Comment: The line is $\Bbb R v$, which passes through zero, but need not "start" at zero. By definition $\Bbb Rv=\{\lambda v\mid \lambda\in \Bbb R\}$, so for $\lambda=0$ it passes through zero.

Comment: @bochner.martinelli If you want to think of a vector as an arrow, then yes in math it starts at $0$.